# rounder corner media view

Tags: android, xml, view

I create a ads type **native advance** for my app, with code below

```
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView
                android:id="@+id/mv_ads"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_140sdp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_mute"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_22sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_mute"
                android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sound"
                android:tag="play"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mv_ads"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mv_ads" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name_ads"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gulzar_regular"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Bộ sưu tập skin súng v1"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_logo_ads"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mv_ads" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo_ads"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_6sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/bird"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/mv_ads"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mv_ads" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_des_ads"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_3sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_8sdp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:includeFontPadding="false"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:text="16-10-2-22"
                android:textColor="#9E9C9C"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/bt_call_action"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/iv_logo_ads"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_name_ads" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/bt_call_action"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_68sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_26sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_navite_ads"
                android:text="Conent"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/mv_ads"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mv_ads" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/bt_call_action" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.NativeAdView>
```

If i use card view, interface will rounder corner all side, i do not want to that, i want to just 2 side rounder corner
How i can rounder corner for **media view** side top right and top left.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code with filename background.xml in res/drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/black" />

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
                android:topRightRadius="100dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and just add

> android:background="@drawable/background"

in your Linearlayout and try once.